# Is $f(x)$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

$f(x)=x^4+x^2+x+1$

Is $f(x)$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

**My attempt:**

Since $f(x)$ is monic, every rational root of $f(x)$ is an integer that divides the constant term. So, the only candidates for rational roots of $f(x)$ are $1$ and $-1$.

$f(1)=4$ and $f(-1)=2$.

So, $f(x)$ does not have any rational roots. So, it does not have any linear factors. But it could be a product of $2$ irreducible quadratics. How do I determine whether this is the case?

Comment: Write the presumed factorization as $(x^2+ax\pm 1)(x^2+bx\pm 1)$. Proceed.

Comment: It might be helpful to note (from a result somewhat ambiguously called [Gauss's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_(polynomial))) that monic integer polynomials $f(x)$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ if and only if irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde:  The lacuna "..." in the title of that proposed duplicate may be ambiguous, but if cyclotomic polynomials are intended, note here the omitted $x^3$ term.

Comment: @hardmath Oops, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way: $\ f(2) = 23$ is prime so $f(x)$ is irreducible by [Cohn's irreducibility test.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohn%27s_irreducibility_criterion)

Comment: An instructive answer, but one not accessible to a student beginning in abstract algebra :P

Comment: @ted The proof of Cohn's test is short and simple, so certainly accessible..

Comment: It might be worth a small expansion of your Answer to give a tailored demonstration (and thus motivate the OP to study the linked article).

Answer (score 0):

Working from the comment of @ThomasAndrews, I notice that if $f$ is product of two quadratics, they must be $x^2+ax+\varepsilon$ and $x^2-ax+\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ is either $1$ or $-1$.

Reason? If the linear coefficients of the quadratic factors are $a$ and $b$, then the cubic coefficient of the product is $a+b$. In the same way, the product of the constant terms must be $1$, so they are inverses of each other and of absolute value $1$, thus equal.

But $(x^2+ax+\varepsilon)(x^2-ax+\varepsilon)=x^4+(2\varepsilon-a^2)x^2+1$, with no linear term. So $f$ is irreducible.